# Questions about non-unique ODE solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Is the only way to show part 1 to just plug in the y, y' and y''. Because y'' is pretty messy and I was thinking there might be an easier way. Also I know how to do part 2 and then check again in part 3. But could someone break this down for me. Why does it work like this and where does this come from?

Comment: No, in part 1 you can derive the solution. But that is much more painful than just checking the solution that is provided.

Comment: You could alternatively calculate $g''(x)$ for $g(x) = \sqrt{t} y_1(t)$ (but not using the expression for $y_1$ here) and show that the equation implies $g''(x) + g(x) = 0$ and then show that $\sin(x)$ is a solution of this (if you did not know that beforehand).